# How to properly align vmatrices vertically

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices

I am having a problem properly aligning these vmatrices vertically.  My output currently looks like:

[image]

Can you help me properly align these matrices?  Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,x11names,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
b_{0} & = \begin{vmatrix}
         0.01822 & 1 \\
         1 & 0.01822
       \end{vmatrix} & = -0.9997, &\quad
b_{1} & = \begin{vmatrix}
         0.01822 & -0.25 \\
         1 & -0.0891
       \end{vmatrix} & = 0.2484, &\quad
b_{2} & = \begin{vmatrix}
         0.01822 & 0 \\
         1 & 0.5265
       \end{vmatrix} & = 0.0096, &\\[3pt]
b_{3} & = \begin{vmatrix}
         0.01822 & -0.825 \\
         1 & -0.825
       \end{vmatrix} & = 0.8100, &\quad
b_{4} & = \begin{vmatrix}
         0.01822 & 0.5265 \\
         1 & 0
       \end{vmatrix} & = -0.5265, &\quad
b_{5} & = \begin{vmatrix}
         0.01822 & -0.0891 \\
         1 & -0.25
       \end{vmatrix} & = 0.0842 &
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it that you would like to align all numbers vertically, including the ones inside the various matrices. If that's the case, the following solution may be of interest to you.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,mleftright,booktabs}
\sisetup{table-format=1.5,group-digits=false} 
\newenvironment{mymat}[1]{%
  \mleft\vert \begin{array}{@{}#1@{}}}{%
  \end{array} \mright\vert}

\begin{document}
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}

\begin{align*}
 b_{0} &= \begin{mymat}{S S[table-format=-1.5]}
         0.01822 & 1 \\
         1 & 0.01822
       \end{mymat} = -0.9997, 
&b_{1} &= \begin{mymat}{S S[table-format=-1.4]}
         0.01822 & -0.25 \\
         1 & -0.0891
       \end{mymat} = \phantom{-}0.2484, 
&b_{2} &= \begin{mymat}{S S[table-format=-1.4]}
         0.01822 & 0 \\
         1 & 0.5265
       \end{mymat} = 0.0096,\\ 
\addlinespace
 b_{3} &= \begin{mymat}{S S[table-format=-1.5]}
         0.01822 & -0.825 \\
         1 & -0.825
       \end{mymat} = \phantom{-}0.8100, 
&b_{4} &= \begin{mymat}{S S[table-format=-1.4]}
         0.01822 & 0.5265 \\
         1 & 0
       \end{mymat} = -0.5265, 
&b_{5} &= \begin{mymat}{S S[table-format=-1.4]}
         0.01822 & -0.0891 \\
         1 & -0.25
       \end{mymat} = 0.0842 .
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just realized a problem. When I tried your approach, and there is a `-` sign in the first element of the matrix, the `-` sign goes outside of the `|  |`.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Joe - I'm not sure I understand the issue. Is there something stopping you from placing a `-` symbol ahead of `\begin{mymat}`?

Comment: no, for example, if the matrix is `c_{0} & = \begin{mymat}{S S[table-format=-1.5]}
         -0.9997 & 0.0842 \\
         0.0842 & -0.9997
       \end{mymat} & = \phantom{-}0.9922, &`, the `-` sign falls outside of the matrix lines.  Thanks.

Comment: For such a matrix, you need to change the argument of `mymat` from `S S[table-format=-1.5]` to `S[table-format=-1.4] S[table-format=-1.4]`. "`-1.4`" means: "LaTeX, please set aside enough horizontal space for a `-` symbol, 1 digit before the decimal marker, and 4 digits after the decimal marker."

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

Ampersands had to be properly distributed: one in equation, one between equation:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}   % <-- added
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,x11names,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
b_{0} & = \begin{vmatrix}
         0.01822 & 1 \\
         1 & 0.01822
       \end{vmatrix} = -0.9997, &
b_{1} & = \begin{vmatrix}
         0.01822 & -0.25 \\
         1 & -0.0891
       \end{vmatrix} = 0.2484,  &
b_{2} & = \begin{vmatrix}
         0.01822 & 0 \\
         1 & 0.5265
       \end{vmatrix} = 0.0096, \\[3pt]
b_{3} & = \begin{vmatrix}
         0.01822 & -0.825 \\
         1 & -0.825
       \end{vmatrix} = 0.8100, &
b_{4} & = \begin{vmatrix}
         0.01822 & 0.5265 \\
         1 & 0
       \end{vmatrix} = -0.5265, &
b_{5} & = \begin{vmatrix}
         0.01822 & -0.0891 \\
         1 & -0.25
       \end{vmatrix} = 0.0842 
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Note: your equation is very long and can't be placed in text width even if you defined page margins to 20mm (now are spilled out on the right side).

Comment: is it possible to line them up around the `=` sign?  Thanks!

Comment: which one?, you have now around all of them, so you have discrepancy in aligning :(

Comment: OK, I see, I guess that it will be difficult to align around all the `=` as some of them have a `-` sign.  Thanks for your help!